# How can i display element one by one by pushing the oldest and the new one will be on top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have an array of objects, the objects are comments.
I want to display all the comments but first will be 3 comments and from the forth comment it will render to the top and push the other comments down.
(CSS,HTML,Java script)

my code

````
function createComment(comments) {
  for (let i in comments) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let item = comments[i];
      const { name, image, date, content } = item;

      let comment = new Comments(name, image, date, content);
      comment.renderToHtml();
    }, 1000 * i);

```renderToHtml() {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "comment col-lg-12 border p-1 mt-3 text-right";
    id_row.appendChild(newDiv);

    newDiv.innerHTML += `<img
        src="${this.image}"
        alt="${this.name}"
        width="80"
        class="float-right m-1 border img"
      />
      <h5 class="name">${this.name}</h5>
      <p class="date">${this.date}</p>
      <p class="content">
        ${this.content}
      </p>`;
  }
````

for now its display comment one by one with 1 sec delay but its not pushing the oldest to the bottom.. the new comment always will be the last

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: i tried to do it short as i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```js
id_row.appendChild(newDiv);
```

by

```js
id_row.insertBefore(newDiv, id_row.firstChild);
```

the method `insertBefore` works the same as `appendChild` but it inserts the element before the element passed as second argument

`id_row.firstChild` being the first element, the new div will be inserted at first position

### [edit] how to show 3 comments then others

```js
function createComment(comments) {
  for (let i in comments) {
    let item = comments[i];
    const { name, image, date, content } = item;

    let comment = new Comments(name, image, date, content);

    const timeout = 0;
    if (i < 3) {               // for the first 3
       comment.renderToHtml(); // render immediately
    else {                         // for the others
      timeout = 1000 * (i-3);      // calculate a timeout that grows 
                                   // (1 second more for each comment)
      setTimeout(() => {
        comment.renderToHtml();     // then only call setTimeout for renderToHtml
      }, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow amaizing! now the last problem is how can i display for the first time the page rendered only first 3 comments and then after a delay to display the others one by one like now

Comment: @DavidNahum - this forum is not intended for discussions. Your question has been answered and should be marked as such. You should create a new thread for another question, rather than asking it here in the comments. :)